# If $\langle x^a \rangle \leq \langle x^b \rangle$, then $(b, n) \mid (a, n)$. I have proved something false

Tags: group-theory

I have already seen a proof to the above lemma in this site. But when I was trying to prove it, I got a incorrect result, and I don't know where I have made a mistake.

Assuming $\vert x \vert = n$. If $\langle x^a \rangle \leq \langle x^b \rangle$, then:

$x^a \in \langle x^b \rangle$

$x^a = (x^b)^k = x^{bk}$

This implies that:

$a \equiv bk \mod{n}$, So:

$n \mid a - bk$

$(b, n) \mid n$ so $(b, n) \mid a - bk$.

Also $(b, n) \mid bk$. Therefore:

$(b, n) \mid a$

Because $(b, n) \mid n$ and $(b,n) \mid a$ we have $(a, n) \mid (b, n)$.

But this result is not true, because if $\vert x \vert = 12$

$\langle x^6 \rangle \leq \langle x^3 \rangle$, but $6 \nmid 3$

Comment: How did you conclude that $(a, n) \mid (b, n)$? You seem to be assuming that the greatest common divisor divides any common divisor. It’s the other way around.

Comment: @Steve You are right. Got that wrong.